# How to edit a recieved JSX element to attach a prop to any img element inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I want to be able to add a onLoad/onAbort prop to any image or video element inside a JSX element passed to my function.

I'm creating a gallery component that accepts JSX elements and displays them in a selected pattern. The idea is that any JSX element can be passed in and it will be formated and displayed. In order for this to work properly, especially the sorting algorithms that do multiple passes, I need to know when the images and videos have loaded and taken on their native resolutions so that i can scale them and preserve the ratios. To do this I want to attach a onload and onabort property to every image contained inside a JSX element passed to my function that updates my component state telling the component the image has loaded.

I'm not sure how to do this because there is no restriction on the structure of the incoming JSX element. It could have any level of nesting and the image or video could be anywhere inside that structure. If I were doing it post-render I'd do:

```
   //gridRef.current is the grid element ref I get through useRef()
   const images = gridRef.current.querySelectorAll('img');
   images.forEach((image, index) => {
      if (image.complete) //mark current image as already loaded
      else {
         image.onload = () => {
            //mark current image as loaded after it loads
         };
         image.onabort = () => {
            //mark current image as loaded after it aborts
         };
         image.onerror = () => {
            //mark current image as loaded after it errors out
         };
         //mark current image as not loaded yet
      }
   });
```

And the same for videos. I don't want to do it post rendering, though, because the image could load after the image.complete check and before the listener being attached which would cause a bug. It'd be much more natural to do this before even rendering the element, but how?

I'd want one of the following:

1) Something similar to image.complete property that tells me if all the elements descendants are loaded, so if I used it on my grid element it would return true only after all the images in all the descendant nodes have loaded. Then I could do this check post-render and wouldn't need to edit the JSX.

2) A way of searching through the JSX element hierarchy and retrieving then editing all the img and video elements.

3) A property that fires a function when all a components descendants have loaded.

4) Anything else that achieves the same goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this which I am currently using is to just have a recursive timeout that looks at all the images fetched by

```
   const images = gridRef.current.querySelectorAll('img');
```

and checks image.complete for every one and if they're all true it calls my sort function, if not it calls its self and checks again after a timeout. It works well enough for images, but the video element doesn't have a .complete prop.

edit: video has a .readyState prop which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the element and then clone their children recursively. Add the props you want before cloning children based on their types to do it in post-render way.
Example of function:

```
function editJSX(Component, newProps = {}) {  
  return React.cloneElement(Component, newProps, React.Children.map(Component.props.children, c => {
    let myProps = {};
    if(c.type === "img") {      
      myProps =  {onLoad: handleOnLoad};
    }
    return editJSX(c,myProps); // recursion
  }));
}
```

Full demo with a check for all images being loaded: https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-lalande-uhymj